# Networking: NAT two interfaces together on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, routing, openvpn, nat

I have the following setup:

- Openvpn client (Linux) (Openvpn IP `192.168.99.4`)
- Openvpn client (Windows) (Openvpn IP `192.168.99.2`)
- Openvpn server (Linux) (Openvpn IP `192.168.99.1`)

Now, both clients connect to the server. From the Linux client, I want to be able to access the subnet of the ethernet interface (`10.137.137.0/24`) of the Windows client. This subnet has a number of other devices on it.

This is what I managed to get so far:

From the Linux client, I am able to ping the windows client on the other interface by adding another route:

```
sudo ip route add 10.137.137.0/24 via 192.168.99.2
```

Unfortunately, I am only able to ping the Windows client `10.137.137.1`, not other devices on that subnet (e.g., `10.137.137.2`).

I want to be able to do this.

Some further info: here is the client-specific openvpn configuration for my windows client:

```
iroute 10.137.137.0 255.255.255.0
```

Furthermore, I have enabled IP forwarding on the Windows machine in `regedit`.

I know that this post is very similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/877085/windows-10-as-a-router-nat-incoming-nic-1-traffic-out-via-nic-2), but I cannot configure Routing and Remote Access on my machine (as shown in the answer), as the option is simply not there in the admin tools.

Moreover, I know I can manually add a route on `10.137.137.2` to route requests from the OpenVPN interface to `10.137.137.1`, but this does not scale well in a large network.

Comment: Is the machine running a Server edition of Windows? The full RRAS is generally a Server-specific feature; Windows client editions can do a limited version of NAT (e.g. for Internet Connection Sharing and for Hyper-V) but I'm not sure if it's possible to enable it for arbitrary interfaces.

Comment: …Is the network really large if it uses Windows machines for routing, and if it doesn't have any dynamic routing protocol in place? In any larger network you'd have something like OSPF and the route would propagate across the network automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by enabling Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on the ethernet interface, sharing it with the OpenVPN interface. Finally, I restored the IP address of the OpenVPN interface, as Windows changed it in the process of enabling ICS.